# Parallel.Foreach delegate invoking another delegate

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Is there anything wrong with this code or can this be done more efficiently?  In particular, i'm a little concerned about the code within parrallel.foreach firing/invoking a delegate.  could this potentially cause any issues?
I ask because currently the consumers are unable to keep up with the items being produced in many cases, leading to memory issues.

```
public delegate void DataChangedDelegate(DataItem obj);

public class Consumer
{
    public DataChangedDelegate OnCustomerChanged;
    public DataChangedDelegate OnOrdersChanged;

    private CancellationTokenSource cts;
    private CancellationToken ct;
    private BlockingCollection<DataItem> queue;

    public Consumer(BlockingCollection<DataItem> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
        Start();
    }

    private void Start() {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        ct = cts.Token;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(), ct);
    }

    private void DoWork() {

        Parallel.ForEach(queue.GetConsumingPartitioner(), item => {
            if (item.DataType == DataTypes.Customer) {
                OnCustomerChanged(item);
            } else if(item.DataType == DataTypes.Order) {
                OnOrdersChanged(item);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there multiple consumer instances created?  If yes, why not just have one static instance processing the queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In particular, i'm a little concerned about the code within parrallel.foreach firing/invoking a delegate. could this potentially cause any issues?

In general terms, there's nothing wrong with calling a delegate from within the `Parallel.ForEach` method.

However, it does make it more difficult to control thread safety, as the delegate will take on the requirements to handle all data synchronization correctly.  This is mostly an issue since the main reason to use a delegate is to allow the "method" that you're calling to be passed in, which means it's being supplied externally.

This means, for example, that if a delegate happens to call code that tries to update a user interface, you may be in trouble, as it will get called from a background/ThreadPool thread.

Comment: thanks.  is it unreasonable to expect the above consumer to handle a queue  that is being added to by a loop indefinitely (with no delay..i.e. really really fast)?  i'm essentially trying to test whether the consumers can keep up in such (rare) cases..thus far they can't and eventually i run out of memory.

Comment: @mike01010 Pretty much - unless you have multiple consumers.  The partitioning/scheduling overhead will never match how fast you can add items in a fixed loop... So you'll eventually get behind.  You'd need either some throttling on add, or multiple consumers processing...

Comment: im not sure that will help..isn't parrallel.foreach suppose to attempt to spawn threads as needed (effectively doing the same thing that multiple consumers would)?

Comment: @mike01010 It does, but there's overhead involved.  If the producing side is effectively "free" - it's going to be very tough to keep up, even with multiple consumers.

Comment: hmmm..for some reason, the code is spawning endles threads (until OOM), even when the queue is empty!